# How to split a JavaScript String by commas and dots?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to split strings by commas and dots using javascript. For example, a string of `"10,256,326.26"` would turn into `["10", "256", "326", "26"]` after getting split.

Which regex can I use for this?

Comment: Google "split a JavaScript String by comma's and dots" and the top results  will tell you almost exactly that.

Comment: Didn't  find it on google, only replace

Comment: Why is this consider too broad? Isn't the question clear enough?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a `character class` containing all characters on which you want to `split`

```js
var s = "10.269,69";
document.write(s.split(/[,.]/))
```

Comment: @Jonas good..enjoy..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` with a regex:

```
console.log(str.split(/,|\./));
```